# Trouble with installation of Steam on CentOS 8

Tags: steam, centos-8

After updating graphics card and during installation of Steam on CentOS 8 I get:

```
[root@comp pawel]# yum install epel-release
    Error:
     Problem: conflicting requests
      - nothing provides libxcrypt-compat(x86-32) needed by steam-1.0.0.66-2.el8.i686

[root@comp pawel]# yum install libxcrypt-compat
No match for argument: libxcrypt-compat

[root@comp pawel]# yum install libxcrypt

libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.i686 is already installed.
```

I have epel version:

`epel-release-8-8.el8.noarch` is already installed.

How to install Steam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That installs on my EL8 system without any broken dependencies:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://negativo17.org/repos/epel-steam.repo
sudo dnf yum -y install steam
```

Comment: Older Steam package is not longer available.

Comment: Try the el7 package, it should work: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/steam-1.0.0.49-1.el7.i686.rpm.html Steam updates itself anyway, so package version isn't particularly critical.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1007005)

Comment: @music2myear there is no critique or request for clarification. The fact is that the dependencies on the latest el8 rpm are broken, and the only solution is indeed to install an older version of the package that is not broken.

Comment: This is a comment because it lacks the How necessary to fix the problem. If you were to add even rudimentary steps of how OP is to go about doing this it would make this basic and bare statement into an actual answer.

Comment: @music2myear, there, added both the latest working link for el8, and how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a x64 machine:

```
sudo dnf -y remove libxcrypt-4.*.i686
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libxcrypt-compat-4.4.17-1.fc34.i686.rpm
sudo rpm -Uhv libxcrypt-compat-4.4.17-1.fc34.i686.rpm --nodeps
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on CentOS 8 stream, as Nov. 2020

Comment: I think you meant to say `x86_64` for 64-bit, as `i686` is 32-bit.